# Font-awesome icon inside anchor link becomes unclickable at certain screen resolutions

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor, font-awesome

I am using Font-awesome 5.11.2 in an Asp.net mvc core project.

I have the icon nested in an anchor link inside a table, I'm using MDBootstrap table. The icon appears and seems to work for my screen resolution, but when I change to 1280 x 1024, hovering over the icon doesn't change the mouse cursor and click doesn't seem to work. Changing to a smaller or slightly larger resolution fixes the issue.

The people testing the application will all use 1280x1024 resolution screens so it won't work in their machines.

**EDITED**

I have used MDBootstrap to make the table look a little similar Angular Material. Here is the code:

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-hover table-striped shadow-lg" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-sm">Name</th>
      <th class="th-sm" style="max-width: 150px;">Date of Purchase</th>
      <th class="th-sm" style="max-width: 120px;"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Customers)
    {
      <tr class="productRow" id="@item.id">
        <td>@item.Firstname @item.Lastname</td>
        <td>@item.PurchaseDate</td>
        <td>
          <div style="padding: 5px;">
                <span style="float:left;">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Info", "Customer", new { id = item.id, pageID = Constants.Page2 })" class="DetailLink">
                        <i class="fas fa-pen"> </i>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span style="float:right; padding-right: 5px;">
                    <a data-link="@Url.Action("_DeleteCustomer", "Customer", new { id= @item.id, CustomerStatus = ViewBag.CustomerStatus })"
                       data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog-box" class="CustomerLink">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"> </i>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }        
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how I need to initialise the table to get the MDBootstrap css and javascript activated:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "first_last_numbers"
    });
    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you remove the `fa-lg` tag do you still have the same issue at the screen resolution 1280 x 1024?

Comment: Oh yes, I tried going without fa-lg, with normal sized icons. Then I tried fa-2x (starts to get too big and ugly), fa-3x and its the same.

Comment: So if you just have the tag `<i class="fas fa-pen"> </i>` i.e. without any `sizing`, does it work correctly at the screen resolution 1280 x 1024?

Comment: I tried it without the fa-lg. It works but when I zoom in then after a few zooms the icon's click doesn't work, like let's say I zoom in on 110% it doesn't work, but zooming again at 120% works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm going to recommend, it sounds like the issue with non-responsiveness at the screen resolution 1280 x 1024 is due to the `scaling` being applied to the `FontAwesome` icon.

The scaling options for `FontAwesome` as per [Font Awesome Sizing Icons](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons):

[image: Font Awesome Sizing Icons]

Using the `fa-lg` tag has implied styling such as `vertical-align: -25%` which may result in unexpected results.

You can apply `font-size` as an attribute to any `FontAwesome` `<i>` tag and I would recommend in this instance just to substitute that custom styling instead.

You can use `font-size: 1.33em` as an equivalent for `fa-lg`, see it's implementation below:

```css
a .fa-pen {
 font-size: 1.33em;
}
```

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "SomeController", new { id = item.id })">
                        <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                    </a>
```

Let me know if this resolves your issue!

Comment: Hi, thank for the suggestion. I tried it and that perfectly takes care of the size. But the underlying problem is still there :( I have 2 icons next to one another - a pen for eidt and trash can for delete. Somehow the pen works, and when I applied font-size: 1.33em style on fa-trash-alt, the trash can doesn't work. Somehow it won't respond to any clicks. When I zoome in or Zoom out, then they work for some reason.

Comment: I found a pattern where zooming on 110% make the icon non responsive to clicks, but then 120% zoome or 130% makes it work. Or if i go to a certain resolution, if it doesn't work, then zooming in/out makes it work.

Comment: I would suggest supplying the outer code to your example, perhaps the issue lies there